# How can I properly listen to HTTP JSON POST requests in PHP?

Tags: php, http, post, webhooks, slack

I need to **listen to a HTTP POST request** and respond to it. How can I **listen to such a request**?

**How can I listen to HTTP Post requests**? **What will be the URL the POST request has to be sent to?** **How can I make the program always listening** without using hacks such as `while(!file_exists("stop.txt")) {}`?

**Please note that I'm NOT coding a website**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To listen to a POST request with a PHP program all you need to do is have a web server running with a PHP script that accepts a POST request.

You not need any code that wait for a request (e.g. `while(!file_exists("stop.txt")) {}`) . That part is covered by the web server, which will call your scripts once it receives a HTTP request.

In your PHP script you need to process the request, which is done by reading the magic variable `$_POST`.

Here is a simple example for receiving a HTTP POST request with a parameter "payload" that has data in JSON.

Btw. a good way to generate your own POST request is with tools like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/)

```
<?php

$request_json = $_POST["payload"];
$request = json_decode($request_json);
print_r($request);
```

The URL will depend on where the webserver is running. e.g. it will be something like `localhost/path/to/run.php` if you run it locally.

Comment: `all you need to do is have a web server running with a PHP script that accepts a POST request.` That is probably easy though not for me. Can you please explain how I could do this? Thanks for your answer. @Erik Kalkoken

Comment: Sure. You want to install a complete stack with Apache, MySQL and PHP. An Windows I can recommend Wampserver: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: Then you need an editor /  IDE. There are many good options to choose from, personally I prefer VIsual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: And once I have installed this, can I just create a simple PHP script in var/www that checks if $_POST is not empty and handles it? Will that be always listening?

Comment: wait, are we talking Linux? then you want to install a LAMP stack instead with `apt-install`

Comment: Yes, Linux. Will have to run it on productivity shortly. @Erik Kalkoken

Comment: Alright. Here is an example for Ubuntu 18.04: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: In general yes. Once you properly installed and configured Apache and PHP on your Linux system it will always run your PHP script when it received a request at the respective URL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Correct - the script answers, if its called - Apache2 (or another webserver-software) has to run and acts as "Listener" - if that makes it more easy for you to understand. Its like a website - theres also no script listinening for visitors - the called page just gets delivered by the webserver ;-)

Comment: @LetsPlayNebulous Allow me to add that setting up a Linux webserer with PHP for production is not trivial. I do not know your level of expertise, but be sure to harden your system properly against security attacks, e.g with a firewall, SSL, SSH with keys, etc.

Comment: @Erik Kalkoken I don't think I have any additional security software installed, what would you recommend me?

Comment: This is an extensive topic. At the very least I would setup SSH with ssh keys only, move it to a random port, enable a firewall like UFW, disable memory sharing. And run your webserver with HTTPS. Here is a great guide to start with: https://www.dexbot.info/2018/06/07/step-by-step-guide-to-secure-an-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-part-1-of-2/

Answer (score 2):

I dont know, if I get your question correct. If you just want to answer, if a post request is send to you, you could write a simple php script:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)):
 // Post was sent and you can do stuff with it and response
 $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
 echo json_encode($arr);
else:
 echo "Nothing to see here, because no post was sent";
endif;
?>
```

So this script answers when someone sends a post to that uri, where the script is located.
As in the answer below mine, your server doesnt need to actively "listen" ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What will be the URL the POST request has to be sent to? @Mario

Comment: that depends on where you put the script. If you have a webserver running (for example apache2) the default root directory for a homepage would be "/var/www/html/" (Linux)
If you put your script there, then your script answers at yourdomain.tld/yourscriptname.php